# Create session number based on column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below pandas Dataframe with user_id and the event.

I want to identify different search sessions based on the events that occurred.

When a user shifts from event A to B, that would be 1 search session only. If the same user, after coming from A --> B goes to A again, that would be a new search session. When the user_id changes, also the search number changes.

What I explained for A --> B can also happen from B --> A. So, when the user starts with and event B and goes to an event A, then it would be one unique search session.

Extra note: A --> B journeys or B --> A can have as many times A and B in a row.

Extra note 2: sometimes a search it's just a sequence of As or a sequence of Bs.

Below the two columns I have (user_id, event) and the column I'd live to get to: search.

| user_id | event | search |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | search_1 |
| 1 | A | search_1 |
| 1 | B | search_1 |
| 1 | A | search_2 |
| 2 | A | search_3 |
| 2 | B | search_3 |
| 2 | B | search_3 |
| 3 | B | search_4 |
| 3 | A | search_4 |
| 4 | B | search_5 |
| 4 | B | search_5 |

Do you have any ideas? the example table contains some examples mentioned before

Thanks in advance

Comment: please verify
user_id->event->search
1->B->search_1
1->A->search_2...
and then..
3->B->search _4
3->A->search _4
 the two raw are right or not as it bit confusing..

Comment: it's correct,  as I mentioned in the question: "If the same user, after coming from A --> B goes to A again, that would be a new search session."
It's the same user but a new session because it completed already the A-B cycle

Comment: @Sarin Consider the example where for `user_id=1` we have the following sequence `['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']` of events. What should be the expected output in such a case?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma  in that case it would be search_:
1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below code logic is self-explanatory if still need an explanation let me know

```py
user = []
event = set()
count = 0
ls_event_id = ""
ls_user_id = 0
def search_id(user_id,event_id):
    global count, ls_event_id, ls_user_id
    if ls_event_id != event_id or ls_user_id != user_id:
        if user_id not in user:
            user.append(user_id)
            event.clear()
            event.add(event_id)
            count += 1
        elif user_id in user and event_id not in event:
            event.add(event_id)
        elif event_id not in event:
            event.add(event_id)
            count += 1

        if len(event)==2:
            event.clear()
            user.clear()
            
    ls_event_id = event_id
    ls_user_id = user_id
    
    return f'search_{count}'


df['search'] = df.apply(lambda x:search_id(x.user_id,x.event),axis=1)
```